# GET MAX ID ROW OF A TABLE

Tags: android, sqlite, max

My question is about how get the max id row of a table... I'm using max function but give me a error

[image]

Here is my code

```
     public static long getLastIdQuotaAdded(Context context){
    long id;
    Cursor cursor;
    String selection = null;
    String[] selectionArgs = null;

    selection = "MAX(" + C_ID + ")";

    cursor=context.getContentResolver().query(URI, ALL_COLUMNS, selection, selectionArgs, null);
    id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(C_ID));
    return id;
}
```

Thank you for yout help... :)

Comment: Can you copy/past your error ? Your picture is cut in the middle...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query (even the part that is visible) is not valid SQL.

To get the maximum value of a specific column, use something like this:

```
SELECT MAX(_id) FROM mytable;
```

In SQLite, if your ID is *the* Row ID (see [the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid)), you can just do:

```
SELECT last_insert_rowid();
```

Answer (score 3):

there is a table named `sqlite_sequence` in `SQLITE` that is used to store the `auto_increment_key`.

this is the query to get latest `auto_increment_key` values.

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT seq FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name=?",
                new String[] { TABLE_NAME });
int last = (cursor.moveToFirst() ? cursor.getInt(0) : 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to get max id of a table....

```
   public static long getLastIdQuotaAdded(Context context){

    Cursor cursor;
    String selection = null;
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    selection = "SELECT MAX("+C_ID+") FROM sessaoquota";

    cursor=context.getContentResolver().query(URI, ALL_COLUMNS, selection, selectionArgs, null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        do{
            idMax = cursor.getInt((0));
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());

    return idMax;
}
```