# Update on Content Provider does nothing

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to make an Android app to help people suffering from headaches. I have a sqlite database to store the crisis, and users can add a crisis by pushing a button. The same button is used to indicate the crisis is over. In other words, when you feel the headache coming, you push the button ; then, when it's over, you press it again and the application updates the corresponding entry whith the "end date".

But if my insert does well, my update does not update at all. Here is how it is supposed to work :

I first retrieve the latest entry in my database (which is the one with the greatest id), then I get the actual date, and put it in a ContentValue. Finally I update the entry.

Here is the button code :

```
public void onClickStartStop(View v){
    Log.v("andromed", "Starting/Stopping crisis");
    String d = new Date().toString();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    String user_info = "";
    String[] projection = {CriseContract.COLUMN_NAME_CRISE_ID, CriseContract.COLUMN_NAME_CRISE_DEBUT,CriseContract.COLUMN_NAME_CRISE_FIN};
    Cursor criseCursor = getContentResolver().query(CriseContract.CONTENT_URI, projection,"SELECT MAX("+CriseContract.COLUMN_NAME_CRISE_ID+") FROM "+CriseContract.TABLE_NAME, null, null);
    Log.v("andromed",""+criseCursor.getCount());
    if(criseCursor.getCount()>=0){
        while(criseCursor.moveToNext()){
            String date_fin = criseCursor.getString(criseCursor.getColumnIndex(CriseContract.COLUMN_NAME_CRISE_FIN));
            if(!(date_fin==(null))){
                Log.v("andromed","Date exists "+date_fin);
                user_info = "Crise enregistrée";
                cv.put(CriseContract.COLUMN_NAME_CRISE_DEBUT, d);
                Uri u = getContentResolver().insert(CriseContract.CONTENT_URI, cv);
            }else{
                String date_deb = criseCursor.getString(criseCursor.getColumnIndex(CriseContract.COLUMN_NAME_CRISE_DEBUT));
                if(date_deb==null){
                    Log.v("andromed","No date in db");
                    user_info = "Crise enregistrée";
                    cv.put(CriseContract.COLUMN_NAME_CRISE_DEBUT, d);
                    Uri u = getContentResolver().insert(CriseContract.CONTENT_URI, cv);
                }else{
                    Log.v("andromed", "Need to close the crisis");
                    cv.put(CriseContract.COLUMN_NAME_CRISE_FIN, d);
                    int tmp = getMaxId();
                    String where = CriseContract.COLUMN_NAME_CRISE_ID+"="+tmp;
                    String[] st = {""+tmp};
                    int nup = getContentResolver().update(CriseContract.CONTENT_URI,cv, where, null);
                    Log.v("andromed", nup+" rows updated");
                    user_info = "Crise terminée";
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        user_info = "Erreur lors de la lecture";
    }
    Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),user_info, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    t.show();
}
```

(Don't mind the Log and the toast stuff, just for me).

Here is my function to retrieve the maximum id :

```
private int getMaxId(){
    String[] projection = {CriseContract.COLUMN_NAME_CRISE_ID};
    String selection = "SELECT MAX("+CriseContract.COLUMN_NAME_CRISE_ID+") FROM "+CriseContract.TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(CriseContract.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);
    Log.v("andromed", ""+c.getCount());
    int maxid=-1;
    if(c!=null){
        while(c.moveToNext()){
            maxid = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(CriseContract.COLUMN_NAME_CRISE_ID));
        }
    }
    Log.v("andromed", "Greatest id in table Crise : "+maxid);
    return maxid;
}
```

And of course, my contract class :

```
public final static class CriseContract{
    public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.piertris.andromed";
    public static final String BASE_PATH = "database";
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://"+AUTHORITY+"/"+BASE_PATH);
    public static final String CONTENT_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE+"/"+BASE_PATH;
    public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE= ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE+"/andromed";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "crises";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_CRISE_ID = "criseid";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_CRISE_DEBUT = "date_debut";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_CRISE_FIN = "date_fin";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_INTENSITE = "intensite";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_SYMPTOM = "symptome";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_MED = "prise_med";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_MEDS = "type_med";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_AURA = "aura";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COMMENT = "comments";

}
```

When I try to end the current crisis, my Logcat tells me that 0 rows were updated.

Thanks to SO, I already corrected other problems due to a wrong use of the function, but this time, the only link I found was this one : [Android content provider not updating database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578553/android-content-provider-not-updating-database) and the OP just added a comment saying he updated his ContentProvider, but nothing more.

What am I doing wrong ? Did I "misnamed" my column names ? Do I misuse the update function ?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**

Thanks to Jozua, I realized that I didn't implement the update function in my ContentProvider file. Alright, I feel extremely dumb right now. I'll keep you informed on how does it work once the update() function is written.

Once again, thanks Jozua.

Comment: An app  for headaches huh...cool

Comment: @hiphopdroid Hey, school projects, you know...

Comment: Yep @vrashnak, I know

Comment: @hiphopdroid well, at least it's still interesting, but quite difficult.

Comment: Difficult things are always interesting to those who are curious ;)

Comment: It would help to also have your ContentProvider implementation. From what I can tell, it is not standard. For example, this code: getContentResolver().query(CriseContract.CONTENT_URI, projection,"SELECT MAX("+CriseContract.COLUMN_NAME_CRISE_ID+") FROM "+CriseContract.TABLE_NAME, null, null);   It should not work because the selection argument should only contain the SQL where clause.

Comment: Hi @Jozua, thanks for answering. Actually, this "Select" stuff is my where clause since i need my ID to be the maximum one for it is the latest inserted. Moreover, I found this way of getting my max ID in answers for another question here on SO where it was said to be the best way for doing it and the most respectful of Android programming good practices. Nevertheless, as soon as I get back my PC, I'll post my ContentProvider here.

Comment: @Jozua and it actually works since I've been testing the app :)

Comment: Yes I assume you tested it. But it is still strange because that line sets a projection but also uses 'SELECT MAX(...)' in the selection parameter, that means the projection is overwritten somewhere. Probably in your content provider. If you say it is most respectful of Android programming good practices, I have to strongly disagree. But I'd like to see the ContentProvider code before I suggest improvements.

Comment: @Jozua I have to disagree. My projection here is ID, DATE_DEB and DATE_FIN. My WHERE clause is "SELECT...". In raw SQL, it would give something like "SELECT ID, DATE_DEB FROM TABLE WHERE ID=(SELECT MAX(ID)...);" but raw sql seems bad. Still, you'll have my ContentProvider by 9PM (French hour), but I don't think it will be of any use.

Comment: I have written an ORM framework that optimizes use of SQLite using content providers. It's used in all of our apps, both for B2B and B2C. I kind of do know what I'm talking about. You seemed to want help, so I thought I'd help you. I hope I'm not wasting my time.

Comment: @Jozua I need help. I'm just surprised that an accepted answer with quite a lot of upvotes found here on SO and (according to what I found here and there) providing what is supposed to be compliant to Android programming good practices (and here, I just quote other people here on SO) seems not to be the right way of doing it. Here is one of the links that led me to this way of coding : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006624/android-select-max-in-contentprovider Now, if you have a better way of implementing it, I'd be delighted to get it :)

Comment: @Jozua another link backing my way of coding : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356568/get-max-id-row-of-a-table once again, just a use of a "raw SQL" as a selection, but not projection.

Comment: @Jozua nevertheless, thanks to you I realized I made a huge beginner mistake. (Luckily I had someone who could have a look at my file while I can't). Thanks for giving me time. In addition, I'd say I never wanted to say that you did not know what you were talking about, but rather explaining my choices as I would have done with anyone. Hope I didn't vexed you.

Comment: No problem. So long as you'll learn than I'm happy to help. After you update with the content provider code I'll respond to your comments and go into detail on how I would've solved your use case. I'm sure it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I kind of solved the problem, but in a really bad way.

Considering the fact that I retrieve the crisis just once in order to add almost everything that is needed but the beginning date and the id, I simply turned my update() request into a delete() followed by an update() in which I pass a ContentValue containing the values of the row I previously deleted.

I know it is really bad programming, but at least it works.

I won't accept my answer, in case someone find out what was wrong with my update() function and could possibly help someone else (and even me, so that I can improve my code).

That's it :)

Here is the portion of relevant code :

```
public void onClickStartStop(View v){
    //go straight to relevant part
    String date_deb = criseCursor.getString(criseCursor.getColumnIndex(CriseContract.COLUMN_NAME_CRISE_DEBUT));
    Log.v("andromed", "Need to close the crisis");
    cv.put(CriseContract.COLUMN_NAME_CRISE_ID, criseCursor.getInt(criseCursor.getColumnIndex(CriseContract.COLUMN_NAME_CRISE_ID)));
    cv.put(CriseContract.COLUMN_NAME_CRISE_DEBUT, date_deb);
    cv.put(CriseContract.COLUMN_NAME_CRISE_FIN, d);
    int ndel = getContentResolver().delete(CriseContract.CONTENT_URI, CriseContract.COLUMN_NAME_CRISE_ID+"=?", new String[] {""+criseCursor.getInt(criseCursor.getColumnIndex(CriseContract.COLUMN_NAME_CRISE_ID))});
    Log.v("andromed", ndel+" rows deleted");
    Uri u = getContentResolver().insert(CriseContract.CONTENT_URI, cv);
    user_info = "Crise terminée";
    //End of relevant code
}
```

Thanks to those who might have searched anyway.